# iOS: Keep playing music in background with Spotify SDK

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, spotify

I'm using the Spotify iOS SDK and have a question about the background music.

When a user locks the phone or presses the Home button I want my app to continue to play the music. How is this possible?

I've tested

> NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
>
> NSError *activationErr  = nil;
>
> ```
> [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
> [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
> ```

Together with adding "Required background modes" to the apps plist.

Does this require that the AVAudioPlayer is used? Since I'm using the Spotify streamingPlayer its not possible.

Comment: Not sure about the Spotify SDK, but you might want to try setting the  MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Background playback should work just fine. You do need the `audio` item in your `UIBackgroundModes` Info.plist entry, though. Also, make sure you test on a device - I know remote control events don't work in the iOS Simulator, and that might be the case for background audio as well.

The iOS SDK will automatically set up the `AVAudioSession` for you, so you don't need to do that.

You might find this answer helpful, which is more in-depth: [Background Audio with cocoalibspotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532819/background-audio-with-cocoalibspotify).